# Instruments - Leaks : Extended leaks not showing code location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have plenty of memory leaks in my game... however when I am looking through them the Leaks Instrument and pull open my Extended Detail, i don't see a single useful code class or method for any of them. They all have a long list of items, but they are called things like:

```
CSEventRunMidal
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
-[UIWindow sendEvent:]
```

But every tutorial I look through they just simply double click the method or class call, but i dont see any of that available. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the extended detail view isn't providing good information, switch to the call tree view by using the jump bar. To the left of the call tree view is the Call Tree collection of checkboxes. Selecting the Invert Call Tree and Hide System Libraries checkboxes helps you quickly find your code in the call tree view. Double-clicking one of your functions in the call tree view will show you the lines of code that allocate leaked memory.